# Dynamic List is duplicated on DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, datagrid

So the problem is next:
I have a table in SQL in which I have the amount of columns that are not predefined (May be different amount and different columns in different DBs). That is why I can NOT predefine all the values. i am using the dynamic list.
[non duplicated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW6FI.png)

This is my View

```xml
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Content="Attributes" />
                                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TestCollection, ElementName=DataGridWO}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

This is my ViewModel

```cs
                    // SELECT top 1 'GB40' AS[STORAGEPLANT], 'W' AS[PARTSORIGIN], 'Zelena Street 12' AS[STREET] 
                    dynamic d =await  _workOrderAttributesService.GetWorkOrderAttributesDynamic(jobNumber); 
                    List<dynamic> dynamicList2 = new List<dynamic>(); 
                     dynamicList2.Add( new {
                         STORAGEPLANT = "StorPlant2",
                         PARTSORIGIN = "D",
                         STREET = "Shevchenka Street 1" 
                          });
                    dynamicList2.Add(d); // if I add this before adding predefined - duplication is happening
                    TestCollection = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>(dynamicList2);
```

[duplicated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDq06.png) 
Here are the outputs on the DataGrid on the first if I add dynamic object after the predefined one - it is NOT duplicated. But I need actually to add only this not predefined object - and if I do that - it is duplicated in One row I get all the parameters twice.

More information about the problem: I can not use predefined columns because it may differ, I need something that is super flex. I have added an SQL example in comments: So my SQL, for example returns:

NAME AGE POSITION and the values are 
                                     
 "Peter" , "21" , "Boss".

Why would it show on data grid as 
                                            
  NAME AGE POSITION NAME AGE POSITION and the values are     
              
 "Peter" , "21" , "Boss" , "Peter" , "21" , "Boss"?

Why it duplicates columns But if I add some predefined object and then get from await - the result is only 3 columns with no duplication?

Comment: Playing with dynamis is dangerous. I guess that `d` returned form `await` is a list, that consisting of one item, not a single object e.g. `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Thus `DataGrid` creates redundant columns. Try strong typed solution.

Comment: Hi, actually I can not use predefined columns because it may differ, I need something that is super flex. I have added an SQL example in comments:   So my SQL, for example returns:  NAME  AGE  POSITION    and the values are  "Peter" , "21" ,  "Boss".  Why would it show on data grid as  NAME  AGE  POSITION  NAME  AGE  POSITION    and the values are  "Peter" , "21" ,  "Boss" , "Peter" , "21" ,  "Boss"? Why it duplicates columns But if I add some predefined object and then get from await - the result is only 3 columns with no duplication?

Comment: Maybe `DataTable` then?

Comment: Hit the debugger and inspect d

Comment: @Goodies it shows nothing as it is dynamic